# Action Links in Class located in Subdirectory of Plugin

Tags: plugin-development

A class for action links in a plugin loads properly if the class is placed inside the main plugin.php file. If the class is moved to a separate file located in a subdirectory of the plugin then the class loads but the action links fail to load on the plugin page.

```
class XenWord_Action_Links {

 public function __construct() {
    $this->load_filters();
 }

 public function load_filters() {
    $basename = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
    $prefix = is_network_admin() ? 'network_admin_' : '';
    add_filter( "{$prefix}plugin_action_links_$basename", array ( &$this, 'xenword_plugin_action_links' ) );
 }

 public static function xenword_plugin_action_links( $links ) {
    $settings_links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( null, 'admin.php?page=xenword' ) ) . '">Settings</a>';
    $settings_links[] = '<a href="http://www.xenword.com" target="_blank">Docs</a>';

    array_unshift( $links, $settings_links );

    return $links;
 }

}

new XenWord_Action_Links();
```

I've checked that the require_once loads the php file page in the subdirectory by simply adding a var_dump below the new class line. The object loads.

Is this a bug in WP or something in my code?

Tested WP 4.3 and 4.4 beta 4.

Comment: `$basename` no longer refers to the main plugin file.

Comment: @Milo Thank you. The $basename is supposed to point to the main plugin file but I've tried so many combinations now and still cannot get things to load. Trying to follow https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/issues/137

Comment: @Milo -- Let me try to be more clear -- seems like `$basename = plugin_basename( plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . 'xenword.php' );` should work but it isn't returning the action links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to thank @Milo for the answer. The issue was the `$basename` and `dirname()` helps locate the correct directory.

```
$basename =  plugin_basename( plugin_dir_path( dirname( dirname( dirname( __FILE__) ) ) ) . $this->plugin_slug . '.php' );
```